# Nginx can't access root directory in sites-available

Tags: linux, nginx, server

I have basic nginx set up on my Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu). I have only one root user. In my nginx configuration file in location I have

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name site.com;

    root /var/www/html/site;
}
```

I tried to change it to

```
root /root/site
```

But it gives me 403 Forbidden error. When I change it to nginx default directory

```
/var/www/html/site;
```

everything works fine.

Why is it giving me that error? I understand that only root user has access to root directory, but why can't browser only read files from there? Is it okay to create another folder, not like "/var/www/html/23rdsquad;" somewhere on my server (not /root or /var/www) and use that instead?

Comment: I guess there is some permission error as appears in error 403. Check if the target machine has allowed access to NginX machine IP on specified port. Also, check if target machine (hosting your application) is actually running the application server (apache, etc.).

Comment: @MuhammadHannan there is no application server, I have only html/css files. So, you mean the Linux system itself can have permission on Nginx on specified port?

Comment: Dear, it is fine if you want to deal with just static contents. Otherwise, normally for dynamic contents we have a server setup. `NginX` itself is a server and has capability to address static contents. However, `NginX` service should have read permission to the directory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww, I actually was not sure where to ask this kind of question, but now I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Nginx user does't have permission to read directory /root/site, so:

- Check directory permission

  `user@user:~$` ls -l /root/site | grep site

  drwxrwxrwx  7 user user 4096 ago 17 16:56 site
- Check `Nginx` user

  `user@user:~$` ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep
- `Nginx` user configuration is "`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`"

  `vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

  Usually you have
  "user **www-data**;"

---

1) Change directory permission either `Nginx` user.

2) Restart `Nginx` service

```
user@user:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```